# Capybara cannot find dropdown list

Tags: ruby, capybara

I'm working on some automation things with Capybara + Ruby.
There is a dropdown list at the page and I need to click it and select the option. The problem is - its Google Play Console and all styles and ids are dynamic and change every page reload, so you cannot use them. Also, tags names do not help at all.

**Could you help me to find the element and to choose the right option, please?**
For now, it works like this:
`browser.find(:xpath, '/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/section/div[4]/div/fieldset/label[1]/div[2]/div').click.find(:xpath, '/html/body/div[12]/div/div/div/div/div[1]').select_option`
**I need to find a way to do so without using 'xpath'**

Sorry for the screenshots. Didn't find the right way copying code from the browser
So, `'Select an application type'` is a placeholder of this dropdown list, which has two options: `'Applications'`, `'Games'`. I need `'Applications'`.

[image]

Adding a screenshot of options HTML for your reference:

[image]

Comment: Try `puts page.body` to print the content of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
store_listing = browser.find_link(title: 'Store listing')
store_listing.click

application_type = browser.find(:element, 'div', role: 'button', text: 'Select an application type')
application_type.click
browser.find(:element, 'div', role: 'option', text: 'Applications').click

category_type = browser.find(:element, 'div', role: 'button', text: 'Select a category')
category_type.click
browser.find(:element, 'div', role: 'option', text: 'Shopping').click

browser.fill_in(type: "email", with: "contact@cityhive.net")
browser.click_on('Save draft', wait: 100)
sleep 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Capybara's `select` and `select_option` methods are designed to work with HTML `<select>` and `<option>` elements, although `select_option` is doing what you expect because the driver you're using is devolving to just `click` when used on an element that's not an `<option>`. In this case, you're dealing with a JS widget dropdown list so you'll need to just use the `find` methods and `click`.

You don't show the structure of the HTML for the actual choices that are displayed so I can't provide you with exact instructions for that, but for the initial click on 'Select an application type' any of the following would be a better option than what you have

```
find(:label, 'Select an application type').click
find('div[role="button"]', text: 'Select an application type').click
find(:element, 'div', role: 'button', text: 'Select an application type').click
```

For the option you want to select after that, assuming the widget continues using aria roles and uses a role of 'option', you could do something like

```
find('div[role="option"]', text: 'Applications').click
```

If my guess on the role being used for the option is wrong then update accordingly

Comment: Yes, you are actually right regarding the options HTML structure. Sorry, I just added the HTML for the options. I succeded to find the dropdown field with ```find(:label)``` approach but didn't for the options itself it didn't work for now